Find dates which are not in given Date Range
I have a application where I need currency conversion rates which are stored in my database.
I have a table where I store the currency rates as below

I want to find out if for any date, I do not have the conversion rate in my database so that I can insert it.
Consider I do not have conversion rate for a week from the above table, the result should give me all those 7 dates which do not have rates.
I created a Calendar table which stored all the dates for last 10 years. But I am not sure, How can I join both the tables to get the dates from calander table which does not exist in FromDate and ToDate from CurrancyRate table
Script to create Calendar table as below
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE Table_Name = 'Calendar' AND Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE')
BEGIN
DROP TABLE [Calendar]
END

CREATE TABLE [Calendar]
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(d, 3650, @StartDate)

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO [Calendar]
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @StartDate)
             
      END


Please do not use images, use table markdown

Please also show both sample data and desired results.

What's wrong with a NOT EXISTS or a LEFT JOIN (using the Calendar table as the "right" table)?

Note: Your calendar table is for the next ten years, not the previous. Also, it's not complete, you're skipping some days because of leap years. Also, if you're only interested in dates, why use DateTime and not just Date?

Honestly, in the latest version of SQL Server creating a calendar is extremely trivial. For example: DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(YEAR, -10, GETDATE()); SELECT DATEADD(DAY, GS.Value,@StartDate) FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, DATEADD(YEAR, 10, GETDATE()))) GS; for ±10 years. In no (supported) version of SQL Server, however, is a WHILE loop the correct solution.

You can also check for gaps by comparing RateFromDate with LAG(RateToDate) OVER(ORDER BY RateFromDate).

As a side note, when working with date/time ranges, it is often better to use half-open intervals, where the start date/time is inclusive and the end date/time is exclusive (typically 00:00 the next day). The end of one interval would then exactly equal the start of the next adjacent interval. A test for inclusion would then be testValue >= startDateTime AND testValue < endDateTime. (Note the use of < instead of <=. This avoids magic values like 23:59:59.997, which would be different for a SMALLDATETIME, different for a DATETIME2, and different for a .Net DateTime type.

Your requirement "to get the dates from calendar table which does not exist in FromDate and ToDate from CurrencyRate table" translates directly to
SELECT * FROM Calendar C WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CurrencyRate R WHERE C.Date >= R.RateFromDate AND C.Date < R.RateToDate). Alternately, you can check for gaps with SELECT PriorRateToDate AS GapStart, RateFromDate AS GapEnd FROM (SELECT *, LAG(RateToDate) OVER(ORDER BY RateFromDate) AS PriorRateToDate FROM CurrencyRate) X WHERE DATEDIFF(day, PriorRateToDate, RateFromDate) > 1.

The script from Thom A & T N are both pretty good. However, the GENERATE_SERIES() function is only available in SQL 2022 at the moment. If you're using SQL 2019 or earlier versions, I'd recommend other ways to generate the calendar table. Do NOT use WHILE loop, because its performance is very poor.
Option 1 with recursive SQL and common table expression (CTE):
-- Define the start and end dates
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2030-12-31';

-- Create the calendar table using a recursive CTE
WITH CalendarCte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS CalDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalDate)
    FROM CalendarCte
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalDate) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT CalDate
FROM CalendarCte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5000); -- Allow recursion to continue beyond the default 100 levels

Option 2 with CTE only:
-- Define the start and end dates
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2020-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2030-12-31';


-- Create a tally table with numbers from 1 to 1000000
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tally') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Tally;
CREATE TABLE #Tally (N INT);

WITH E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
               SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),  -- E1 has 10 records.
     E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), -- E2 has 10*10=100 records.
     E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), -- E4 has 100*100=10,000 records.
     E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E4 b), -- E8 has 10*10,000=100,000 records. This is already more than enough for 200 years.
     CteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E8)
INSERT INTO #Tally(N)
SELECT N
FROM CteTally


-- Generate the calendar table. Since the tally table starts with 1, we need to make it minus 1 to start with zero.
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.N-1, @StartDate) AS CalDate
FROM #Tally T
WHERE T.N <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1

Remember to add a INTO #Calendar clause for one of the above SQL that you choose. With the created #Calendar temp table, use the script below from T N.
SELECT * 
FROM #Calendar AS C 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM CurrencyRate AS R
        WHERE C.CalDate >= R.RateFromDate AND C.CalDate <= R.RateToDate
    )


Correction: < R.RateToDate should be <= R.RateToDate, since RateToDate is inclusive.  (My error from my earlier comment.)
